# Command in Maple

Tags: conformal-geometry, maple

I am looking for a possibility to draw the image of the two sets $$\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\text{Im}(z)>0,\text{Re}(z)=1/2\}$$ and $$\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\text{Im}(z)>0,|z|=1\}$$ under the map $z\mapsto\frac{z-i}{z+i}$ with Maple. It would be nice if this lines could be in the same plot.

I have read that the command `conformal` can help here?

I am looking forward to your answers. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a code that you can copy/paste.

```
with(plots):
A := conformal(z, z = .5 .. .5+1.*I, color = [green, red]):
B := conformal((z-I)/(z+I), z = .5 .. .5+10*I, numxy = [200, 200], color = [green, red]): 
C := complexplot(exp(I*x), x = 0 .. Pi):
E := complexplot((exp(I*x)-I)/(exp(I*x)+I), x = 0 .. Pi):
display(A, C);
display(B, E);
```

The command "with(plots)" loads the necessary package to use the next commands.
"conformal(f(z),z=a..b)" produces the image of a grid from the point $a$ to the point $b$ on the complex plane. With "color=[X,Y]", we can define the color of the grid and "numxy" determine the number of sample for every line of the grid. Try modifying the values and see what it does.

"complexplot" is a command for plotting complex values. It is used like a normal "plot" here but takes complex values instead.

Finally "display" is used to combine multiple plots. The first one here displays the graph of the sets and the second one the image of those sets under the function $z\mapsto\frac{z-i}{z+i}$.

Note that I could have used "complexplot" only since the set you are working on are curves and that "conformal" produces grids. But I think it is a good thing that you can see what both commands do.

Comment: Thank you! How can I scale the axis in the conformal command? For example I want the output be scaled from x=-1.. 1 and y=-1.. 1?

Comment: Use the option "view". Like this : "conformal(z, z = .5 .. .5+1.*I, color = [green, red], view = [-1 .. 1, -1 .. 1])"

Comment: Yep, that's it! The last thing I need is a caption of the figure which is created with the display command. Is it also possible to put math typesetting (tex) in the caption?

Comment: To add a title, use the option "title" in the plot command (like view, colors...). To add text where you want on the graph, use the command textplot.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood me: I want to use latex in the title. Is that possible? :)

Comment: I think it is impossible. But you can still write titles formulas and text in titles using the option typeset. For exemple : plot(1/x, x = 0 .. 4, title = typeset("Plot of ", 1/x, " , the inverse of ",x,"."))

Comment: And how can the symbol $\mathbb{Z}$ can be set? And are subscripts also possible? I want $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: Try to copy paste this : title = typeset(SL[2], "(&Zopf;)"). To enter specific characters, you can use the symbols available on the left side of maple (depending on the version you have). Maple uses unicode, so if you do not find what you want in Maple, use this page and just copy paste : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_operators_and_symbols_in_Unicode

Comment: Thank you! There is now still one "cosmetic problem": The code is like 'A:=conformal: B:=complexplot(..., title= xy): display(A,B);' the code seems only to be for the part which is drawn with 'complexplot' but it should be for the 'display' part. The output is right but in order to get the code more intuitive: is there something as display(...,title=xy)?

Comment: you can replace, in "display(A,B)", A and B by their expression instead if you like. Like this for example : display(conformal(z, z = .5 .. .5+1.*I, color = [green, red]), complexplot(exp(I*x), x = 0 .. Pi)). But the code is more hard to read like this I think.

Comment: Yeah and that does not solve the problem since the title is still part of one part figure and not the whole one.

Comment: You can use most plot options as option for display as well. For example : display(conformal(z, z = .5 .. .5+1.*I, color = [green, red]), complexplot(exp(I*x), x = 0 .. Pi),title= "Your title")